# Passing An Array Into PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that has different inputs. One of these sections is static, and the other is dynamic. For example, the `practice` and `address` fields below will not change on each form submission, but the `firstName`, `lastName`, and `type` will be arrays. What I am trying to do is find a way to send this form submission to a mySQL database. I am somewhat new to PDO, and am certain there will be a need to utilize a `foreach` loop to prepare a statement(s), but I've searched all over and am having trouble finding a method for this.

Here is a `<pre>print_r</pre>` of the `$_POST` submission as a sample.

```
Array
(
    [practice] => Doctors Office
    [address] => 123 Medical Lane
    [firstName] => Array
        (
            [1] => John
            [2] => Robert
        )

    [lastName] => Array
        (
            [1] => Smith
            [2] => Jones
        )
    [type] => Array
        (
            [1] => MD
            [2] => NP
        )
)
```

Update:
The possible duplicate marked answer doesn't appear to display the `$dataArray` input for the `foreach` loop in the solution, which is what I am interested in.

Comment: How exactly are you expecting it to end up in the DB? You can't store an array (you can store a serialized version of any object in PHP, but that's not really the same).

Comment: Prepare the statement outside of the loop, execute it multiple times within the loop as often as needed of course. Multiple prepares of the same statement are unneeded overhead.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I'm wanting each loop of the array to end up as a separate row in the DB.

Comment: @Wrikken Can you demonstrate how to perform this? I'm having a lot of difficulty visualizing how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt i understood your question completely. This is one way to insert individual names to db.

```
foreach ($_POST['firstName'] as $index => $firstName) {
    $firstName_idx = mysql_real_escape_string($firstName) ;
    //$firstName_idx = $firstName_idx . '_'. $index ; //if you want to append id, do this 
    $sql = "INSERT into database (firstName) VALUES ('$firstName_idx')";
}
```

Note: api you are using deprecated use mysqli or pdo, i hope you are using it for learning purpose.